# the meaning of 'she had a whole list going'

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentence is from March 2018 Reader's Digest. What does the sentence mean?

> She had a whole list going.

Comment: You have tagged this question as "meaning-in-context", yet, ironically, you have provided no context. _Reader's Digest_ publishes jokes, snippets, puzzles, recipes, inspirational stories, and articles about sundry topics such as travel, celebrities, film, and gardening. Where did this come from? As a member for over 2 years who has asked more than 140 questions, I'd expect better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the context there is an another possible meaning in addition to that offered by tjp. This could be a rhetorical idiom. The speaker is talking about another female (the **She**) and is enumerating some of her behaviours, or foibles, or boyfriends). By using "a whole list going" we indicate that there are a lot of things to enumerate, more than a person can remember.

Well you know XXX, she can never have too many hobbies; Monday morning its Pilates, afternoon she's at the  bookclub, then Tuesday ... well I could go on, she's got a whole list going!

Example of this [Maggie Dove by Susan Breen](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5gIACwAAQBAJ&pg=PT169&lpg=PT169&dq=%22she%20had%20a%20whole%20list%20going%22&source=bl&ots=-q9-Qx1JQG&sig=Sjhx80bdhRPihPIR0AhacpvCvRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3hMDJrYraAhWKr6QKHYGaArMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22she%20had%20a%20whole%20list%20going%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

It means that she has gone to the trouble of creating a list for just this purpose.  You'd need more context to understand why, but the implication is that going to the extent of creating a list is more than the average person would bother to do.  The subject has put an unusual amount of effort into pursuing whatever it is the sentence refers to.